# How to make stronger colors in three part pannacotta?

Tags: dessert

This weekend I tried to make a three part pannacotta. It was one layer of rasberry pannacotta, one layer of vanilla and one layer of mango/lime.

The taste was a positive surprise but I was not very happy with the colors. The yellow color of mango/lime was almost white and the rasberry layer was not very intense in the color.

I'm looking for more natural colors. Anyone got any ideas?

If there is some kind of fruit with very compact color or something would be awesome.

Comment: I found a guide for natural food coloring, in this example they used white chocolate. Looks like the orange zest would be good for your mango layer and the berries or beet powder for the raspberry. http://eyecandy.nanakaze.net/?p=385

Comment: Thank you very much for this. The blog post is very informative and helpful. I hope I will have the time to try this out in a few hours so I will get back to you with status and pictures.

Comment: @EmilyAnne That girl invented the *chocolatone*! Wow. Very interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of these are natural colorants but also impart a bit of flavor with them.

For the raspberry layer you could use a tiny amount of beet juice to really kick the red.

For yellow colors you have a few options. Saffron can work really well though I'm not sure what mango/lime/saffron tastes like.  Another organic single ingredient is Achiote, which has an extremely mild sweet flavor. It's used for coloring mac and cheese and most processed cheese.

Hope these ideas help.

Comment: Tumeric is another good yellow color, and not too strong in flavor (or as nearly as expensive as saffron); the lime zest might help, too, but it'd add more green than yellow.

Comment: AH!  yes Tumeric,  I knew i was blanking on a really obvious one.  much less flavor would be imparted than the two option i provided as well.